# Differentiating Laplace transform of $dX=cXdt+\sqrt{X}dW$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider a solution $X$ of the stochastic differential equation

$$dX=cXdt+\sqrt{X}dW$$

For $\mathcal{L}(\alpha,t)=E[\exp(-\alpha X_t)]$ I want to show, that

$$\frac{d}{dt}\mathcal{L}(\alpha,t)=(c\alpha-\frac{1}{2}\alpha^2)\frac{d}{d\alpha}\mathcal{L}(\alpha,t)$$

What I did so far is following:

$$\begin{align}
(c\alpha-\frac{1}{2}\alpha^2)\frac{d}{d\alpha}\mathcal{L}(\alpha,t)
&=(c\alpha-\frac{1}{2}\alpha^2)E[(-X_t)\exp(-\alpha X_t)]
=E[(\frac{1}{2}\alpha^2-c\alpha)X_t\exp(-\alpha X_t)]\\
\end{align}$$

By using the function $h(x,y)=\exp(-xy)$ in Ito's lemma, I find

$$\begin{align}\exp(-\alpha X_t)
&=h(\alpha,X_t)\\
&=h(\alpha,0)+\int_0^t(-\alpha)\exp(-\alpha X_s)dX_s+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t\alpha^2\exp(-\alpha X_s)d[X,X]_s\\
&=1+\int_0^t(-\alpha)cX_s\exp(-\alpha X_s)ds+\int_0^t(-\alpha)\sqrt{X_s}\exp(-\alpha X_s)dW_s\\
&\quad\quad+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t\alpha^2X_s\exp(-\alpha X_s)ds\\
&=1+\int_0^t(\frac{1}{2}\alpha^2-c\alpha)X_s\exp(-\alpha X_s)ds+\int_0^t(-\alpha)\sqrt{X_s}\exp(-\alpha X_s)dW_s
\end{align}$$

Now, is it true, that

$$\frac{d}{dt}\mathcal{L}(\alpha,t)=E[\frac{d}{dt}\exp(-\alpha X_t)]=E[(\frac{1}{2}\alpha^2-c\alpha)X_t\exp(-\alpha X_t)]\quad?$$

I find $$\frac{d}{dt}1=0$$

and

$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^t(\frac{1}{2}\alpha^2-c\alpha)X_s\exp(-\alpha X_s)ds=(\frac{1}{2}\alpha^2-c\alpha)X_t\exp(-\alpha X_t)$$

but why is

$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^t(-\alpha)\sqrt{X_s}\exp(-\alpha X_s)dW_s=0\quad ?$$

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: Have you tried solving the SDE and checking directly?

Comment: I do not really understand what you are asking. But moreover, I am interested to understand stochastic integrals better and wonder when $\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^tf(s)dWs=0$ holds. Or if it holds at all.

Comment: I mean solve the sde and find the laplace transform... like I said

Comment: Ah, now I understand it. Unfortunately, I was not able to find the solution, yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

$$\mathbb{E}\int_0^t(-\alpha)\sqrt{X_s}\exp(-\alpha X_s)dW_s=0$$

because this is a Wiener integral. Therefore the derivative is also zero. Does this answer the question?

Comment: Ah, yes, this seems legit! Thanks for your help!